# Problem in setting video thumbnail with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, ytdl, yt-dlp

I'm trying to add thumbnail to a mkv video with the following command: `ffmpeg -y -i video.mkv -i image.jpg -map 1 -map 0 -c copy -disposition:0 attached_pic out.mkv`. However this command replaces all frames in the video with that image and no sound. Am I doing something wrong. I'm using latest version of ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

What you tried works for MP4 file and not for MKV file. Try this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mkv -i image.jpg \
       -attach image.jpg -metadata:s:t mimetype=image/jpeg \
       -c copy out.mkv
```